# How to send GET requests to a server using ESP8266 Serial Wifi module?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, esp8266

I'm working on a simple problem of sending a request to a server using an ESP8266 Serial Wifi module. I use Arduino and ESP8266.

Here is my code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true
SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (10, 11); //10-TX 11-RX

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  ESP8266.begin(115200);
  ESP_init();
}

void loop() {
  sendData("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"192.168.1.38\",3333", 5000, DEBUG);
  String say = "GET /ds HTTP/1.0";/
  String sayCmd = "AT+CIPSEND=";
  sayCmd += String(say.length());
  sendData(sayCmd, 5000, DEBUG);
  sendData(say, 5000, DEBUG);
  sendData("AT+CIPCLOSE=5",1000,DEBUG);
  delay(2000);
}

void ESP_init() {
  sendData("AT+RST", 2000, DEBUG); // reset module
  sendData("AT+CWMODE=1", 2000, DEBUG); // khoi dong module nhu la 1 access point, 1:station, 3: both
  sendData("AT+CWJAP=\"chi\",\"12345678\"", 5000, DEBUG); // SSID va PASS
  sendData("AT+CIFSR",5000, DEBUG); // SSID va PASS
}

String sendData(String cmd, int timeout, boolean debug) {
  String response = "";
  cmd += "\r\n";
  ESP8266.print(cmd);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(cmd);
  long int time = millis();
  while ((time + timeout) > millis()) {
    while (ESP8266.available()) {
      char c = ESP8266.read();
      response += c;
    }
  }
  if (debug) {
    Serial.print(response);
  }
  return response;
}
```

Currently, I can connect to wifi. But there is no response for my request. I can't find the issue.

Please help me to find out this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you send `\r\n` at end of line of GET?

Comment: i didn't. May I need them?

Comment: Yes you need "GET /ds HTTP/1.0\r\n"

Comment: it is still not working :'(

Comment: Aren't you sending `GET /ds HTTP/1.0` twice ? First in `sayCmd`, then in `say`. Try it without the `sendData(say` line.

Comment: thank u for helping me. I solved my question recently. The problem is in my server. It 's node js REstful, so when I use TCP server, I can receive request from ESP8266